# How to make an array, where each element is an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to make an array where each element is an array. I.e. in element (3,4) of the array, there is an array. In essence a lookup table of arrays. How can I do this. I have tried:

```
for x in range(scanData.shape[0]):
    for y in range(scanData.shape[1]):
        responseArrayFull[x][y] = responseArray
```

but I receive the error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (41,60,19) into shape (1)
```

Comment: Please tell us what `responseArrayFull` and `responseArray` and `scanData` are.

Comment: Hi @CodePope - they are arrays of varying size

Comment: `np.array([arr for arr in arrays]).reshape(*scanData.shape, *arrays[0].shape)`